# Rails - undefined method `'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails is throwing a

```
"*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `' for #<Marketplace::Item:0x000001019dd148>"
```

After a .save  or .valid? on @item (example below), I don't see where is the problem, from my Rails knowledge I would say that a column or a method were not setup correctly, but the model is pretty straight and there not much in the controller as well, could my .valid? getting lost due some attribute/param?

item.rb:

```
class Marketplace::Item < ActiveRecord::Base
include Shared::AttachmentHelper 

extend FriendlyId 
belongs_to :musico
has_many :anuncios
has_many :item_images, :dependent => :destroy

#Paperclip
has_attachment :cover,
    :styles => { 
        :large => "741x570>", 
        :medium => "470x611>", 
        :thumb => "235x",
        :thumb_anuncio => "90x90#"  
    },
    :convert_options =>{
        :large => ["-strip","-quality 80"],
        :medium => ["-strip","-quality 80"],
        :thumb => ["-strip","-quality 80"]
    },
   :default_url => "missing-image.png" 

validates_attachment :cover,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/bmp'] },
    :size => { :in => 0..8.megabytes }

#Opcoes do DropDown de STATUS
STATUS = [  "ATIVO", 
            "INATIVO"]

end
```

items_controller.rb

```
def create
    @item = Marketplace::Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        byebug
        if @item.save
            if params[:images]
                params[:images].each { |image|
                    @item.item_images.create(image: image)
                }
            end

            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: "Item criado." }
            format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Backtrace: http://pastebin.com/GrDywzKR

Comment: Please provide more of the backtrace on the exceptiopn. That'll make it easier to see what the issue is.

Comment: Done. http://pastebin.com/GrDywzKR

Comment: Since one of the closest lines to the exception is in `FriendlyId::Base`, I'd start with that. I'm not really familiar with the gem, but [the documentation](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/5.0.5#rails-quickstart) seems to imply that you're supposed to call `friendly_id` with some attribute after including/extending the module. At this point, I'd suggest experimenting a little: does the error go away if you remove the `extend FriendlyId` line, or if you add the configuration? Does it go away if you remove the `validates_attachment` call?

Comment: @Max is right, looks like `friendly_id` ends up doing a `send(something_that_is_nil.to_s)` while trying to build the "friendly ID" for your model. The lack of a `friendly_id :some_column` call in your model and some poor argument specification/parsing and error handling on `friendly_id`'s part would explain the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the comment:

*@Max is right, looks like friendly_id ends up doing a send(something_that_is_nil.to_s) while trying to build the "friendly ID" for your model. The lack of a friendly_id :some_column call in your model and some poor argument specification/parsing and error handling on friendly_id's part would explain the error you're seeing.*

Friendly it was, indeed, the problem, I was missing an include.